# Manage permissions with OpenLDAP

Tags: permissions, ldap, openldap

I'm currently configuring permissions on an existing openldap server using `ldapadd | ldapmodify` and ldif files ([created following these examples](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html)). I'm then testing using `ldapsearch`. All the tests I run as `cn=admin` are successful (not very difficult I guess since it's the built-in all mighty admin account) but I'm just unable to give special permissions to other users (though the bind works). Bottom line is, I found the management of ldap permissions being very painful.

**[Q1] What tools do you use to visualize existing permissions on an LDAP server and change them as needed?**

To manipulate the LDAP directory I use [Apache directory studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/)

**[Q2] What other tools to you use to manipulate the LDAP directory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To visualize and administer LDAP, there are many options, here are [some](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/270.html).

I personally use [ldapsh](http://ldapsh.com/) to perform some quick ldap edits. It visualizes your ldap tree as directory structure which is easy to navigate and make edits using vim or your fav editor.

Answer (score 0):

I use [LdapAdmin](http://ldapadmin.sourceforge.net/). It is windows application and it is pretty good for routine tasks. But it has some limitations if you require full control over your directory.